# How do I get FullCalendar events to stop disappearing while I'm dragging or resizing them?

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar v2, and I just tried enabling the draggable and resizable options for events. It works perfectly except if I have an event that reaches across a few days and try to resize or move it, the events in a different column disappear.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

[image]
[image]

The first picture is how it looks before I click, and the second picture is what happens **while I'm holding the mouse cursor down and extending it**. Every column not on the same day as the draggable area disappears temporarily, and as soon as I let go of my mouse button all of the columns reappear.

This doesn't inhibit any functionality and it saves correctly, it just looks bad. This also occurs if you try and move events rather than resize them.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing, and had the same issue.   In my database I had a field for id, I used json data to populate my calendar.  The database field for id had nothing in it, it was either null or empty string.  So, when I dragged one event, they all moved (or disappeared)

Solution:  I made each id unique, non null, and never an empty string.